# помогите исправить код

Tags: javascript

Проблема с привязкой контекста: не могу разобраться, как привязать, чтобы выводило `this.title` – выводит `undefined`.

```
function bind(func, context) {
    return function() {
        return func.apply(context, arguments);
    };
}

var group = {
    title: "Наш курс",
    students: ["Вася", "Петя", "Даша"],

    showList: function(){
        this.students.forEach(function(student) {
            alert(this.title + ': ' + student);
        })
    }
};


var hi =  bind(group.showList, group);
hi();
```

Comment: `this.students.forEach(function() {/* */}.bind(this));` не?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В соседних ответах почему-то упорно не хотят давать пример с *привязкой* контекста. А я дам:

```
var group = {
    title: "Наш курс",
    students: ["Вася", "Петя", "Даша"],

    showList: function(){
        this.students.forEach(function(student) {
            alert(this.title + ': ' + student);
        }.bind(this));
    }
};
```

А еще, можно навсегда забыть о ручной привязке контекста и начать уже использовать ES6. [Стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (arrow functions) идеально подходят для этой задачи:

```
var group = {
    title: "Наш курс",
    students: ["Вася", "Петя", "Даша"],

    showList: function() {
        this.students.forEach(student => {
            alert(this.title + ': ' + student);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

С контекстом все нормально, как по мне, а вот в определении `group` есть один момент. Попробуйте так:

```js
var group = {
  title: "Наш курс",
  students: ["Вася", "Петя", "Даша"],

  showList: function(){
    var title = this.title;
    this.students.forEach(function(student) {
      //у вас здесь this.title, но в данном, как раз, контексте,
      //this.title не определен, потому мы сохраняем его выше 
      //в доступной области видимости
      alert(title + ': ' + student);
    })
  }
};

group.showList();
```